# Is there a parameter pattern I can add in DataGrip that matches the Python named argument string pattern?

Tags: regex, datagrip

So basically I have some python scripts with strings representing SQL statements with some named arguments, eg:

```py
schdl_stmt = "select * from bar.schedule where date = '{date}'"
```

I uses this to interpolate the date dynamically.

My workflow involves running/debugging these queries in DataGrip, and so I really need a way for DataGrip to utilize this named argument syntax, else I'm stuck manually editing the statement too often.

DataGrip allows you to add custom regex patterns for such a usecase in the settings pictured below:

[image]

However I have not been able to figure out one that works for the Python named argument string pattern.

I've tried:

- `"{name}"`
- `"\{name\}"`

If it's simply not possible because of some caveat with how DataGrip handle's these patterns, that would be useful to know as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct pattern is

```
\{(\w+)\}
```

with 'Substitute inside SQL strings' enabled.

Please read [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/settings-tools-database-user-parameters.html) for more details.

Comment: thank you! so a key component I missed was the exclusion of the `"` from the pattern 